# Is there a Global Online Leaderboard?

Tags: rocket-league

I really want to know how many points the best players have right now.
Also how good my score is. (Score = 420, *not even joking*)

So, is there any leaderboard which contains all players on different Platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's in the main menu under *Extras* - *Ranked Leaderboards*.

Comment: I play it on Playstation, so isn't it Playstation-Players only?

Comment: Well, one of the main features advertised with Rocket League is _crossplay_ between platforms. I would assume that the leaderboards work in the same way. We could do some science to make sure this is actually the case. Currently for me (on PC), #1 on 1v1 is Markydooda with just over 1500 points, followed by kuxir97.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm corrently not at home. Perhaps another one with a PS4 can help us?

Comment: Yes, the leaderbords are the same on PS4 (I checked). Since PS4 and PC players can play together it wouldn't really make sense to keep them separate. You can also see your ranked division on the leaderbord screen. A skill level of 420 should probably put you somewhere around division 9-8.